# Where is Shogunworld physically located?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

At the end of HBO's Westworld, season 1, Maeve wanders into the control center / maintenance center for Shogun World.  It is just adjacent to the control/maintenance center for Westworld.

My sense of the scope of the Westworld park is that it extends for miles and miles in every direction. The control/maintenance center is underneath it.  I suspected it was in the middle of the park, though that's just an assumption.

If the control/maintenance center for Shogun World is just next door to the control/maintenance center for Westworld, but the Westworld control center is directly under the park, it doesn't seem as though Shogun World could be directly above its control center; the two parks would physically overlap.

How are the 2 enormous parks, and their control centers, positioned? I've thought of a few options that could make sense.

1. The Shogun World park doesn't exist yet. They're just creating the hosts and the story lines, and they'll open the park somewhere else, later. It would be a big waste of money to have to move the center later, but it would be useful to have both control centers side-by-side while developing Shogun World.
2. The sky in Westworld is fake.  It's only some small distance (1000 feet, for example) above the ground, and it's just a big TV screen that they color blue with clouds in the day, and black with stars at night.  The whole Westworld park is just one level of this multi-level Delos facility.  The control centers & maintenance centers are underneath, and the park is above. Shogun World is just one more level of the facility, either above or below Westworld, and it also has a fake sky 1000 feet (??) above it.
3. The 2 parks butt up against each other.  The control centers are both positioned on the edge of the parks, rather than being positioned in the middle of the parks, or the control centers span an area just as large as the parks, so their "footprint" just matches the size & shape of the park.

EDIT:

In Season 2, it appears as though Shogun World just shares a physical boundary with Westworld. They're next to each other.

Comment: @Paulie_D I was hoping someone could discover an interview with a producer that shed some light on it. But you might be right.

Comment: Reduced title to make it slightly less spoilery. The existence of Samuraiworld is a surprise. Plus, with the tags, it really isn't necessary to state the show title.

Comment: The season 2 trailer may give us a hint. Notice what a main characters sees at the 35 second mark...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSFZW5efo6M

Comment: @Gnemlock Thanks! I changed "season 10" to "season 1". You're the only person to notice and comment on that in the last year and a half!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly,

### We Don't Know

*In fact, we don't know where Westworld is either.*

But...here's what we do know.

The Control Center (for Westworld) is in the **park** or at least on the edge of it. It's built into a mesa.

[image]

We also have maps (which evolve as the show progresses) of the Westworld park.

[image]
[image]

Now, the Control Center is not indicated on the overall map but since we see mesas in the park it's not a stretch that this is one of them. Probably somewhere along the long mesa "wall" we can see in the screenshots below.

All of this would weigh *against* the two parks being contiguous....but Westworld (the park) is **vast** (Nolan [**confirmed**](http://www.slashfilm.com/where-is-westworld-located/) 500 sq. miles)....so the Control Center could be anywhere.

[image]
[image]
[image]

When interviewed by Entertainment Weekly per [**/Film**](http://www.slashfilm.com/westworld-season-two-details/), producer Jonathan Nolan said:

> After last night’s finale, a lot of you are likely curious if we’ll see more of Samurai World. Although Nolan wouldn’t confirm if that’s what “SW” exactly stands for to Variety, he did discuss the other park.
>
> > "One of the things we’ve established is Westworld is the proto-park. It’s the first park. The other parks, you would imagine, are extensions."

and co-showrunner Lisa Joy

> "We’re definitely teasing there are other worlds. How many other worlds and what is the nature of the other worlds is something we’ll start to explore more in season 2".

---

One final point...I found this on Imgur which is a reasonable analysis of where the Control Center is located...its a little large to add in so I'll just link it.

[http://imgur.com/r/westworld/6KXET](https://imgur.com/r/westworld/6KXET)

Comment: Excellent pics! Looking forward to finding out more about the parks in season 2.

Comment: Ha...I should have answered tomorrow...i'm rep-capped today. :)

Comment: Well I won't mark it as The Answer until tomorrow!

Comment: @BrettFromLA rep caps don't prevent you from getting accept points, only upvote points.

Comment: The first season 2 "teaser" may hint that SW is closer to Westworld than one might think. (Pay attention to a shot of Bernard looking down at the water).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IaPV1VkKfs